# Using testNG @Factory: Instances are run in parallel.

Tags: testng

I have a factory returning array of Mytestclass with different params.
Mytestclass has ten tests which are ordered using dependsOnmethods.

When I run the tests using factory, my first test is run for the first instance. Then the same test is executed for the second instance. After the first test is run on all the instances, it resumes second test on the first instance.
I need it to run all tests on the first instance and then move to second and so on.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the suite xml attribute `group-by-instances=true` and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the tests in parallel mode? Try without it.

Comment: No. I have set parallel attribute to false in my suite. <suite name="regression" parallel="false">. Am i doing it right?

Comment: Looks like that should work, I would try removing it altogether as the default is to not use parallel threads

Comment: i have tried both.. both execute in the same order. My suspicion is on the dependsOnmenthods that I have used on my tests.. will try removing those. Will post the result shortly. But if that is the case then @Factory will not be useful for me.. it'll be too much rework to make my tests parallel-y runnable.

Comment: Tried running the factory by removing the dependsinmethods but same output. It doesnt complete all tests before moving to the next instance.